# SFTP user has access to its public key, is it an issue?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu, sftp

I have set up access over sftp, and the connection is jailed to the home directory of the user.

In that directory is the `.ssh` folder, containing their public key.
Is it a risk that they can access it? Is there some best practice regarding this?

The server runs on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't think you mean public key, because the public key is, as the name suggests, public. But the directory can also contain the private key (`id_rsa` for example). Either way it should not matter, since the key is supposed to be accessible by the owner (user).

If you are afraid the user is going to distribute its private key to others or publish it, then forbid SSH/SFTP access altogether.

If only the user can access the private key, and no one else (excluding root) then there is no reason why you should change the setup.

Comment: I did mean public, thanks. In hindsight it is more clear that it isnt a case.

Answer (score 1):

This is mandatory (in the authorized_keys) for the server being able to decrypt the packets encrypted with the private-key to authenticate.

Moreover the `.ssh` folder and the `authorized_keys` file should be writable only by the user himself, so no other users can add another key to impersonate, if they are not the ssh-server will discard the file and deny access.

Quote from [sshd manpage](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd(8)) manpage for FreeBsd (but true for most openssh installations) :

> ```
>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
>    Lists the public keys (DSA, ECDSA, Ed25519, RSA) that can be used
>    for logging in as this user.  The format of this file is
>    described above.  The content of the file is not highly sensi-
>    tive, but the recommended permissions are read/write for the
>    user, and not accessible by others.
>
>    If this file, the ~/.ssh directory, or the user's home directory
>    are writable by other users, then the file could be modified or
>    replaced by unauthorized users.  In this case, sshd will not
>    allow it to be used unless the StrictModes option has been set to
>    ``no''.
> ```